# how do we pass the address of an int* to a function that uses void ** as parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I have made a stack ADT using void pointers. here are the main and queueFront functions-

```
bool queueFront(QUEUE *queue, void **itemPtr){
    if(queue->count == 0)
        return false;

    *itemPtr = queue->front->dataPtr;
    return true;
}

int main(){
    QUEUE *queue = createQueue();
    int *x = new int(5);
    enqueue(queue,x);
    int *y =new int(10);
    enqueue(queue,y);
    int *getPtr{nullptr};

    queueFront(queue, (void *)&getPtr);
    std::cout << *getPtr << std::endl;
}
```

the book that i am currently using says to use "(void *)&getPtr" while calling queueFront but the compiler gives and error{"invalid conersion from void* to void**"}. I know that using (void **) works but i want to cast int* to void* and then use its address.

Comment: using "&((void *)getPtr)" also gives an error- lvalue required as unary '&' operator

Comment: Whatever book you're using, throw it away and get a better book. There's never a need to mess around with void pointers in modern C++. You're not going to learn proper, type-safe, C++ programming practices from this.

Comment: What's wrong with something like `void *queueFront( QUEUE *queue );`?  Just return `nullptr` if `queue->count` is zero.

Comment: *I have made a stack ADT using void pointers* -- Why?  C++ has a concept called *templates*.   Using as many pointers as you can all over the place does not make a better C++ programmer, contrary to popular belief of newbies and non-C++ programmers.

Comment: I know C++ and have a DS book in C. At present just trying to follow the book ("A pseudocode approach with C") @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @AnshulDimri A "DS" book can be many things. Data Science? Data Structures? Distributed Systems? Something else?

Comment: maybe thats the root of the problem, C is not C++, you can write a stack ADT in C++ the same way you would write it in C, its  just not C++ then

Comment: OT: Please not the Standard Library already provides [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and [std::queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) as container adapters with *different* functionalities, while you are talking about a "stack ADT" called  `QUEUE`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. A `int**` and a `void**` are two different things.

You should create a `void*` then use its address. You can then safely cast that back to `int*` if you know that it points to an `int`.

```
int main(){
    QUEUE *queue = createQueue();
    int *x = new int(5);
    enqueue(queue,x);
    int *y =new int(10);
    enqueue(queue,y);
    void *getPtr{nullptr};

    queueFront(queue, &getPtr);
    std::cout << *(int*)getPtr << std::endl;
}
```

Ideally you'd use a book that wasn't written in 1970 using ancient C idioms; we don't use `void*` pointers any more; we use templates.

Comment: I know C++ and have a DS book written in C. At present just trying to follow the book ("A pseudocode approach with C")

Comment: @AnshulDimri They're two different languages. You can't learn C++ from a C book.